# How to overlay image with color in CSS?

Tags: html, css, overlay

### Objective

I want a color overlay on this header element. How can I do this with CSS?

### Code

```css
#header {
  /* Original url */
  /*background: url(../img/bg.jpg) 0 0 no-repeat fixed;*/
  background: url(https://fakeimg.pl/250x100/) 0 0 no-repeat fixed;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  color: #FFFFFF
}
```

```html
<header id="header">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12">
      ...
    </div>
  </div>
</header>
```

Comment: Please explain "color overlay". What effect are you looking for, exactly?

Comment: That would be too rigid. I want to do A/B test on overlay color.

Comment: Use the developer tools in your favorite browser! Then you will see, that it is simply achieved by a background-image and a background-color with transparency by using RGBA: `.home-page {background: none repeat scroll 0 0 rgba(39, 62, 84, 0.82);`

Answer (score 72, accepted):

You should use rgba for overlaying your element with photos.rgba is a way to declare a color in CSS that includes alpha transparency support. you can use `.row` as an overlayer like this:

```css
#header {
    background: url(../img/bg.jpg) 0 0 no-repeat fixed;
    height: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    color: #FFFFFF
 }

.row{
    background: rgba(39,62,84,0.82);
    overflow: hidden;
    height: 100%;
    z-index: 2;
}
```

Comment: Note the importance of z-index on this one :)

Comment: I'd also like to point out that you can use hsla() or hex with alpha

Answer (score 40):

You can do that in one line of ***CSS***.

```
background: linear-gradient(to top, #3204fdba, #9907facc), url(https://picsum.photos/1280/853/?random=1) no-repeat top center;
```

You can also modify the opacity of a color by hovering over it in VS Code and clicking on it to make it a hex color. It can be shortened to `(#3204fde6, #9907fae6)` instead of the `rgba (rgba(48, 3, 252, 0.902), rgba(153, 7, 250, 0.902)`.

[image]

```css
header {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;
  color: white;
  font: bold 6.5em/2em monospace;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  
  background: linear-gradient(to top, #3204fdba, #9907facc), url(https://picsum.photos/1280/853/?random=1) no-repeat top center;
}
```

```html
<header>Hello World</header>
```

See here [CodePen](https://codepen.io/moghaazi/full/poJEaZp)

[image: z]

Answer (score 15):

You may use negative superthick semi-transparent border...

```css
.red {
    outline: 100px solid rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.5) !important;
    outline-offset: -100px;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
    height: 200px;
    width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div class="red">Anything can be red.</div>
<h1>Or even image...</h1>
<img src="https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/stackoverflow/company/img/logos/so/so-logo.png?v=9c558ec15d8a" class="red"/>
```

This solution requires you to know exact sizes of covered object.

Answer (score 14):

You could use the `hue-rotate` function in the `filter` property. It's quite an obscure measurement though, you'd need to know how many degrees round the colour wheel you need to move in order to arrive at your desired hue, for example:

```
header {
    filter: hue-rotate(90deg);
}
```

Once you'd found the correct hue, you could combine the `brightness` and either `grayscale` or `saturate` functions to find the correct shade, for example:

```
header {
    filter: hue-rotate(90deg) brightness(10%) grayscale(10%);
}
```

The `filter` property has a vendor prefix in Webkit, so the final code would be:

```
header {
  -webkit-filter: hue-rotate(90deg) brightness(10%) grayscale(10%);
          filter: hue-rotate(90deg) brightness(10%) grayscale(10%);
}
```

Comment: Here's a useful tool to generate the filter properties for you: https://angel-rs.github.io/css-color-filter-generator/

Answer (score 11):

Here's a creative idea using `box-shadow`:

```css
#header {
    background-image: url("https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1569442130407-8d2d49e741db?w=500");
    box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 99999px rgba(0, 120, 255, 0.5);
    width: 500px;
    height: 375px;
}
```

```html
<div id="header"></div>
```

What's happening:

1. The `background-image` sets the background for your element (along with the other background properties).
2. The `box-shadow` is the important bit. It basically sets a really big shadow on the inside of the element, on top of the background, that is semi-transparent

Comment: Saved my day with `box-shadow`, many thanks

Comment: Brilliant! Best answer.

Comment: Note that it doesn't correctly work in Chrome / Edge atm.: https://stackoverflow.com/q/72157120/6841224

Comment: This is brilliant. The fact that it doesn't require additional elements makes it the most simple solution. I never thought of this approach. Thank you.

Answer (score 8):

To add an overlay, you can use the CSS background-blend-mode property something like this:

```
#header {
  background: url("img/image.jpg") 0 0 no-repeat fixed;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: hsl(206, 27%, 38%);
  background-blend-mode: multiply;
}
```

Comment: This answer works well with backgrounds that already have the image applied, such as a Wordpress div that had the background image assigned in the page builder. In that case, you can omit the: "background: url..."

Answer (score 6):

```
#header.overlay {
    background-color: SlateGray;
    position:relative;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    -webkit-opacity: 20%;
    opacity: 0.20;
    z-index: 2;
}
```

Something like this. Just add the `overlay` class to the header, obviously.

Comment: If I do this, the content of my header becomes dim too coz of the opacity. Any workaround?

Comment: What you may have to do is create two `absolutely` positioned elements on top one another. One with the image and the other with overlay color.

Answer (score 4):

Use mutple backgorund on the element, and use a linear-gradient as your color overlay by declaring both start and end color-stops as the same value.

Note that layers in a multi-background declaration are read much like they are rendered, top-to-bottom, so put your overlay first, then your bg image:

```
#header {
  background: 
    linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(100, 100, 0, 0.5), rgba(100, 100, 0, 0.5)),
    url(../img/bg.jpg) 0 0 no-repeat fixed;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  color: #FFFFFF
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You can also add an additional class with such settings. Overlay will not overlap content and no additional tag is needed

```
.overlay {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 0;
}

.overlay::after {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: red;
    opacity: .6;
    /* !!! */
    z-index: -1;
}
```

https://codepen.io/zeroox003/pen/yLYbpOB

Answer (score 2):

If you want to just add a class to add the overlay:

```css
span {
  padding: 5px;
}

.green {
  background-color: green;
  color: #FFF;
}

.overlayed {
  position: relative;
}

.overlayed::before {
  content: ' ';
  z-index: 1;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  background-color: #00000080;
}

.stand-out {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 2;
}
```

```html
<span class="green overlayed">with overlay</span>
<span class="green">without overlay</span>
<br>
<br>
<span class="green overlayed">
  <span class="stand-out">I stand out</span>
</span>
```

Important: the element you put the `overlayed` class on **needs** to have a `position` set. If it doesn't, the `::before` element will take the size of some other parent element. In my example I've set the position to "relative" via the `.overlayed` rule, but in your use case you might need "absolute" or some other value.

Also, make sure that the `z-index` of the `overlayed` class is higher than the ones of the eventual child elements of the container, unless you actually want for those to "stand out" and not be overlayed (as with the span with the `stand-out` class, in my snippet).

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind using absolute positioning, you can position your background image, and then add an overlay using opacity.

```
div {
    width:50px;
    height:50px;
    background:   url('http://images1.wikia.nocookie.net/__cb20120626155442/adventuretimewithfinnandjake/images/6/67/Link.gif');
    position:absolute;
    left:0;
    top:0;
}

.overlay {
   background:red;
   opacity:.5;
}
```

See here: http://jsfiddle.net/4yh9L/

Answer (score 0):

In helpshift, they used the class `home-page` as

### HTML

```
<div class="page home-page">...</div>
```

### CSS

```
.home-page {
    background: transparent url("../images/backgrounds/image-overlay.png") repeat 0 0;
    background: rgba(39,62,84,0.82);
    overflow: hidden;
    height: 100%;
    z-index: 2;
}
```

you can try similar like this