# How to add color overlay on an image

Tags: css

So I have an image. I need to put a color overlay `rgba(56, 59, 64, 0.7)` on top of this image.

HTML:

```
<div class="home">
   <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150" />
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.home img {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
```

```css
.home img {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="home">
   <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150" />
</div>
```

Comment: Put another div in the `.home` div, make it the same size and fill it with that colour (use `z-index` if you have to)

Comment: Check this out: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18815157/how-to-overlay-image-with-color-in-css

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Here you go

```css
.home {

}

img {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  display:block;
}

.wrap {
  position:relative;
}

.wrap:before {
  content:"";
  position: absolute;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  height:100%;
  width:100%;
  background: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
  z-index:999;
}
```

```html
<div class="home">
<div class="wrap">
   <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150" />
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: why add another div ? if you can use the `home` div ?

Comment: @MihaiT his assumption was correct, there will be some other content in home. Granted, both answers are correct, but Traver's was more spot on for my case.

Comment: @AliAlmohsen well if that is the case, you should give that info in the question :). We don't ( at least i don't ) have a crystal ball to know what's going on in your html structure

Answer (score 5):

You can use pseudo-elements like `before` and absolute position it on top of the image

Added a blue background color for example purposes , so you can see it better, but you can use any color with opacity

```css
img {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
.home {
 position:relative;
}
.home:before {
  content: "";
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  background: rgba(0,0,255,0.5);
}
```

```html
<div class="home">
  <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

**HTML**

```
    <div class="home">
       <img src="mango.jpg" />
        <div class="overlay"></div>
    </div>
```

**SCSS**

```
.home {
    position: relative;
    img {
        max-width: 100%;
        padding: 0;
        margin: 0;
    }
    .overlay {
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        bottom: 0;
        right: 0;
        background-color: rgba(56, 59, 64, 0.7);
    }
}
```